# column is not contained in aggregate function or group by clause

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to select rows with a query that uses sum.  I keep getting the error `column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`  I add the specified column to the group by clause and it just goes to the next column in the query.  Do I really have to add every single column in the select clause to the group by clause?

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
   s.studentId, s.firstName, s.lastName, 
   c.courseId, c.courseName, c.semesterId AS courseSemesterId, 
   se.semesterId, se.season, se.year, 
   e.enrollmentId, e.studentId AS enrolledStudentId, e.courseId AS enrolledCourseId, e.semesterId AS enrolledSemesterId,
   a.assignmentId, (sum(a.pointsEarned) / sum(a.pointsPossible)) AS percentage
FROM Students AS s
INNER JOIN Enrollment AS e ON s.studentId = e.studentId
LEFT JOIN Courses AS c ON e.courseId = c.courseId
LEFT JOIN Semesters AS se ON c.semesterId = se.semesterId
LEFT JOIN Assignments AS a ON e.enrollmentId = a.enrollmentId
GROUP BY s.studentId, s.firstName, s.lastName
ORDER BY e.courseId
```

Comment: Yes, all columns in the `GROUP BY` clause must be in the `SELECT` except for the columns used in the aggregate function.

Comment: So do you wish do obtain aggregated values from `assignments` or every row from it? cause you actually have `a.assignmentID` in your select list which means you need every row separately.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily, if you use SQL Server 2012 version or above (I believe) you could use the `OVER` clause, like so:

```
(sum(a.pointsEarned) OVER (PARTITION BY s.studentId) / 
 sum(a.pointsPossible) OVER (PARTITION BY s.studentId))
```

Link to msdn article: [OVER Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

Method-1

```
SELECT s.studentId
    ,s.firstName
    ,s.lastName
    ,(sum(a.pointsEarned) / sum(a.pointsPossible)) AS percentage
FROM Students AS s
INNER JOIN Enrollment AS e ON s.studentId = e.studentId
LEFT JOIN Courses AS c ON e.courseId = c.courseId
LEFT JOIN Semesters AS se ON c.semesterId = se.semesterId
LEFT JOIN Assignments AS a ON e.enrollmentId = a.enrollmentId
GROUP BY s.studentId
    ,s.firstName
    ,s.lastName
ORDER BY e.courseId
```

Method-2 (If you need all the columns in the select. You should include it in group by)

```
SELECT s.studentId
    ,s.firstName
    ,s.lastName
    ,c.courseId
    ,c.courseName
    ,c.semesterId AS courseSemesterId
    ,se.semesterId
    ,se.season
    ,se.year
    ,e.enrollmentId
    ,e.studentId AS enrolledStudentId
    ,e.courseId AS enrolledCourseId
    ,e.semesterId AS enrolledSemesterId
    ,a.assignmentId
    ,(sum(a.pointsEarned) / sum(a.pointsPossible)) AS percentage
FROM Students AS s
INNER JOIN Enrollment AS e ON s.studentId = e.studentId
LEFT JOIN Courses AS c ON e.courseId = c.courseId
LEFT JOIN Semesters AS se ON c.semesterId = se.semesterId
LEFT JOIN Assignments AS a ON e.enrollmentId = a.enrollmentId
GROUP BY s.studentId
    ,s.firstName
    ,s.lastName
    ,c.courseId
    ,c.courseName
    ,c.semesterId
    ,se.semesterId
    ,se.season
    ,se.year
    ,e.enrollmentId
    ,e.studentId
    ,e.courseId
    ,e.semesterId
    ,a.assignmentId
ORDER BY e.courseId
```